# How to test the render speed of my solution in a web browser?

Tags: web-development, testing, performance, benchmarking, website-performance

Ok, I need to test the speed of my solution in a web browser, but I have some problems, there are 2 versions of the web solution, the original one that is on server A and the "fixed" version that is on server B.

I have VS2010 Ultimate, so I can make a web and load test on solution B, but I can't load the A solution on my IDE.

I was trying to use [fiddle2](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and [jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), but they only gave me the times of the request and response of the browsers with the server, I also want the time it takes to the browser to render the whole page.

Maybe I'm misusing some of this tools...

I don't know if this could be usefull but:

- Solution A is on VB 6.0
- Solution B is on VB.Net

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's some great tools here - http://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/03/23/sam-s-ultimate-web-performance-tools-and-resources

Comment: did you tried it on Google Chrome F12, traffic ?

Comment: @ElYusubov traffic != rendering

Comment: @devnull, Network and Timeline in Chrome is going to be helpful. That was the things that i wanted to sya.

Comment: @dreza ok, checking them

Comment: @ElYusubov yeah I can also see the traffic with chrom, but its not helping me determinate with the final rendering of the whole page, thx!

Comment: Have you tried [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) (by yahoo) and [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) (by google)? They are browser extensions you can install!

Comment: Yes, I did, but YSlow doesn't work with IE, and PageSpeed is an extension for chrome, I tried that one too, but I need to see the diff cross browsers, Thx!

Comment: [dynatrace](https://www.compuware.com/application-performance-management/ajax-performance-testing.html) supports IE.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer I can suggest is: [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). It is available for Chrome, Firefox, and IE. It can even generate test cases that can be automated by VSTS. You can also create a farm of browser test automation machines to execute the tests.

Answer (score 1):

Good tools for checking website speed and identifying slow areas are [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) and [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/). Neither integrate with the IDE but they give you good feedback.